# What are the character specific achievements?

Tags: overwatch

I was playing as Roadhog and hooked someone mid-ultimate and got an achievement and a Roadhog spray.

Are there achievements for every character? If so, what are they? Does every achievement unlock something?

Comment: You can easily find this information in the client.  Go to Career Profile -> Achievements.

Comment: Many of the other Overwatch questions are things that are readily available in the client. I don't see why this one is any worse.

Comment: @sommerjj I didn't know that was a thing, I tried to find this information on the Hero pages because I figured it was Hero specific and not achievement specific.

Comment: @sommerjj it is somewhat difficult to find. It took awhile for me to find them the first time.

Comment: It is a legitimate question, no need to downvote for just a reason that it's easy to find. Also, it's good to have the reference here as well on Arqade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 achievements per hero, one which unlocks the pixel spray, the other unlocks the cute spray for that hero. You can view them under career profile/achievements. Here is a list of them.

## Offensive

### Genji

- **Their Own Worst Enemy:**
  Kill 2 enemies with a single use of Genji's Deflect in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Slice and Dice:**
  Kill 4 enemies with a single use of Genji's Dragonblade in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### McCree

- **Whoa There!:**
  Interrupt an enemy ultimate ability with McCree's Flashbang in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **It's High Noon:**
  Get 4 killing blows with a single use of McCree's Deadeye in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Pharah

- **Clearing the Area:**
  Knock an enemy to their death using Pharah's Concussive Blast in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Death From Above:**
  Kill 4 enemies in a row without touching the ground as Pharah in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Reaper

- **Waste Not, Want Not:**
  Get 3 solo kills with a single clip of Reaper's shotguns in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Die Die Die... Die:**
  Kill 4 enemies with a single use of Reaper's Death Blossom in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Soldier: 76

- **Rocket Man:**
  Get 2 killing blows with a single use of Soldier: 76's Helix Rockets in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Target Rich Environment:**
  Kill 4 enemies with a single use of Soldier: 76's Tactical Visor in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Sombra

- **Hack The Planet:**
  Hack 15 enemies in a single game of quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Power Outage:**
  Hack six enemies with a single EMP in a game of quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Tracer

- **Total Recall:**
  Recover 400 health using Tracer's Recall without dying in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Special Delivery:**
  Stick 4 of Tracer's Pulse Bombs onto enemies in a single quick or competitive play game.
  Reward: Cute Spray

## Defensive

### Bastion

- **Triple Threat:**
  Kill 2 enemies in each of Bastion's Configurations without dying in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Charge!:**
  Kill 4 enemies with a single use of Bastion's Configuration: Tank in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Hanzo

- **Simple Geometry:**
  Get 2 killing blows with a single use of Hanzo's Scatter Arrow in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **The Dragon is Sated:**
  Kill 4 enemies with one of Hanzo's Dragonstrikes in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Junkrat

- **Mine Like a Steel Trap:**
  Knock an enemy into your Steel Trap using Junkrat's Concussion Mine in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Roadkill:**
  Kill 4 enemies with a single use of Junkrat's RIP-Tire in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Mei

- **Ice Blocked:**
  Block 1200 Damage with a single use of Mei's Ice Wall in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Cold Snap:**
  Freeze 4 enemies at once with Mei in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Torbjörn

- **Armor Up!:**
  Have one of Torbjorn's Armor Packs on 5 allies at the same time in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Raid Wipe:**
  Kill 4 enemies during a single use of Torbjörn's Molten Core in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Widowmaker

- **Did That Sting?:**
  Kill 4 enemies using Widowmaker's Venom Mine during a single quick or competitive play game.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Smooth As Silk:**
  Kill an enemy with a Scoped Headshot while airborne as Widowmaker in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

## Tank

### D.Va

- **Shot Down:**
  Prevent 1500 damage with a single use of D.Va's Defense Matrix in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Game Over:**
  Kill 4 enemies with a single use of D.Va's Self-Destruct in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Reinhardt

- **I Am Your Shield:**
  Block 8000 damage with Reinhardt's Barrier Field without dying in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Storm, Earth and Fire:**
  Land Reinhardt's Fire Strike and Charge after an Earthshatter Stun in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Roadhog

- **Giving You The Hook:**
  Interrupt an enemy Ultimate ability with Roadhog's Chain Hook in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Hog Wild:**
  Knock 2 enemies to their deaths with one use of Roadhog's Whole Hog in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Winston

- **Mine Sweeper:**
  Destroy 10 Turrets or Traps using Winston's Tesla Cannon without dying in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Anger Management:**
  Damage 6 enemies a single use of Winston's Primal Rage in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Zarya

- **Power Overwhelming:**
  Keep Zarya's Particle Cannon above 70 Energy for 60 seconds in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **The Power of Attraction:**
  Capture 5 enemies in a single use of Zarya's Graviton Surge in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

## Support

### Lúcio

- **The Floor is Lava:**
  Get 3 killing blows while wall riding as Lúcio without dying in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Supersonic:**
  Block 1000 damage with a single use of Lúcio's Sound Barrier in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Mercy

- **Group Health Plan:**
  Restore 200 health for 5 players without dying as Mercy in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Huge Rez:**
  Resurrect 4 players at once with Mercy in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Symmetra

- **The Car Wash:**
  Hit an enemy with 7 beams simultaneously as Symmetra in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **Huge Success:**
  Teleport 20 players in a single quick or competitive play game as Symmetra.
  Reward: Cute Spray

### Zenyatta

- **Rapid Discord:**
  Get 4 kills or assists with Zenyatta's Orb of Discord within 6 seconds in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Pixel Spray
- **The Iris Embraces You:**
  Restore 1500 health with a single use of Zenyatta's Transcendence in quick or competitive play.
  Reward: Cute Spray

[Source](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements)